# reset value by group in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

hi i write a formula in crystal report the similar to running total because i cannot use the running total filed for further calculation.but now i am facing a problem that i cannot reset the values by group. i have applied the formula 
numbervar Sump; 
Sump := Sump+{@Variance};

and for resting purpose i added one more formula in the group header.
whileprintingrecords;
shared numbervar Sump := 0;

the reset is not working. please find the snapshot and advice me how to do it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8EW7.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your formulas

1. You define the Sump variable as global in one formula and as shared in the other. Therefore the CR cannot match it. Additionaly, if you declare it global, its scope will apply for all the rows , not only for its group itself
2. You assign the zero value to your variable in the second formula. But consider that this formula is executed for every group, not only once so it will always display zero

Try to write your first formula like this

```
shared numbervar Sump; 
Sump := Sump+{@Variance};
```

and the second like this

```
whileprintingrecords; 
shared numbervar Sump;
```